# Backing Out Of a Grievance

Tags: colleagues, job-security, unions

I have a union protected position at a company located in Canada. Recently, a group of us have been assigned extra work that clearly goes outside the terms of the Collective Agreement.  We filed a grievance as a group. I have less job security then others in this grievance and my understanding was it would be handled as a group. However, management has decided to go with the divide and conquer technique by treating it as individual grievances. I am not affected by this extra work load as much as my coworkers are and there are also a few coworkers that weren't part of it. Ordinarily, a grievance is between the union and management. This is an "expedited grievance" however, which means it's up to us on if it should go to upper management and the union next.

Besides coming up with an exit strategy from my job: Would it be wrong for me to agree that my issue is resolved and back out of the grievance? If it is still handled as a group, can I still back out of it?

Comment: It's right there in the name: "*union*"! What do you think that means?

Comment: Have you told the group they are trying to single you out?

Comment: @noslenkwah Yes. As I mentioned, they are trying the divide and conquer technique.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Former Union Thug(tm) here.

NEVER back out of a union action, and in your case it would be the worst decision.

- Management will have you pegged as someone who is weak
- The union will see you as a rat

You already acted against management, and are on their "list" if they are making one.  It's best to hang with your union brothers because backing out won't save you, but it will get your fellow union brothers to hate you.

Stay the course.  You're already committed, don't look weak.

Edited to add:

There is no possible upside for you in backing out.  If management is going to label you as a troublemaker for filing the grievance in the first place, they won't think any better of you if you back out, so you're not helping your cause in that respect.  Worse, they could see you as being easily cowed.

In terms of the union, backing out may be seen as a betrayal.  Even if your union is one of the more forgiving ones, your best case scenario is that they will not help you in the future, the worst case is they may act against you.  In no case does backing out improve your standing with the union.

If management sees you as easily cowed and the union won't support you, that doesn't bode well for you even if there is no direct reprisals.  Both sides in this will see you as untrustworthy, and that may put you in an undeniable position.

Comment: Hear, hear. Stick with the Union, OP. Why wouldn't you?

Comment: Best solution in the bad situation imho. Do not back out, unless you get something in return and your union rep  approves it.